# Naming of backing properties for protected variable

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to have a `protected` variable in my base class :

```
protected val _networkState = MutableLiveData<NetworkState>()
    val networkState: LiveData<NetworkState>
        get() = _networkState
```

In order to follow Kotlin guidelines for Naming of backing properties﻿ `_networkState` should be private. When it is protected, I receive following warning on the variable : ***property name should start with a lowercase letter***

What is the best practice for naming of my `protected` variable?

Comment: I would just call it `mutableNetworkState`. I don’t think there’s a standard for this.

Comment: I agree @Tenfour04. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

```
private val _networkState = MutableLiveData<NetworkState>()
protected val networkState: LiveData<NetworkState>
    get() = _networkState
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This doesn't expose the `MutableLiveData` to the subclass, which is what the OP wanted.